# How to install packages without interfering existing ones without using yum and without root?

Tags: linux, centos, python

I have this specific problem of setting virtual dev environment without interfering existing system and tool. The question is general.

Basically I want to develop some stuff in the company, but we are using very old Centos 6.4. and I don't have root to run `yum`. I know I can compile from source and install to `~/.local` if I want newer version of certain packages. But doing this would break some tools we are using I guess (eg. some tool relies on `gtk2`, but I build `gtk3` and put it in `~/.local`, the `./local` is in front of `/usr/lib` in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). I know I can install `gtk3` to somewhere else say `~/envs/myEnv1` and manually modify the library path before I want to run my new `gtk3`-based application. But isn't this the same as what `virutalenv` does in Python world? And if more "virtual envs" get involved, the harder to maintain the "envs" it becomes.

So is there a `virutalenv` solution for general software development ? I saw our IS department has a tool which is a wrapper for Python `virtualenv`, and it will build out your `virtualenv` with Python 2.6 using [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/) if you run it. I haven't tried it but according to the doc, it sets up a new development environment without interfering your current system. (I guess I can install any Python packages, and any system packages as I wish?)

Is there an equivalent thing in the outside world? Or this kind of solutions are all done in-house?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need/want an statically linked app. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474329/how-can-i-link-glibc-statically-with-qt) is Q&A for QT but it's similar to gtk3. In general it's quite odd idea (when there is a bug in hardlinked library you need to recompile/relink your app to updated lib) but at least it's an option.